# phpunit Fatal error - require_once not locating files that appear to be on the include path

Tags: phpunit

I've installed phpunit version 3.5.6 using pear and required dependecies using
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit which went fine.

When I run phpunit from the command line such as (phpunit fleet.php) it produces a fatal error and fails opening required files (see sample output image below).

I have checked the include_path using get_include_path and the output is as follows.
c:\PHP; c:\PHP\pear; c:\php\includes; c:\Inetpub\Library;

The system path also contains c:\php\pear

Please advise how to get this running.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be with include paths generally

set_include_path('\php\pear');

I added the above line to c:\php\phpunit before the first require_once statement which goes...
(require_once 'PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php')

After that PHPUnit worked fine. There must be an issue with the include path as read from php.ini

include_path=".; c:\php\pear\; c:\PHP; c:\php\includes; c:\Inetpub\Library; c:\Inetpub\ZendFramework-1.10.6\library"

I have tried...
c:\php\pear\;
c:\php\pear;
\php\pear\
\php\pear

All of the above fail to resolve the path.

Comment: this turned out to be problem with my php installalation and not phpunit

Comment: This issue is also concerned with php versions. Php versions under 5.3 will cause this error